# How to Bind custom shapes on kendoUI Listview from JSON?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

```
var myShapes = [{ "Shapes": '{"path":"M74.5,37.5 C74.5,57.91 57.91,74.5 37.5,74.5 C17,74.5 0.5,57.91 0.5,37.5 C0.5,17 17,0.5 37.5,0.5 C57.91,0.5 74.5,17 74.5,37.5 z","connectors":[{"name":"bottom"}]}', "text": "Start" },
  { "Shapes": '{"path":"m 40,30 c 0,5.522847 -4.477153,10 -10,10 -5.522847,0 -10,-4.477153 -10,-10 0,-5.522847 4.477153,-10 10,-10 5.522847,0 10,4.477153 10,10 z M 30,0 C 13.431458,0 0,13.431458 0,30 0,46.568542 13.431458,60 30,60 46.568542,60 60,46.568542 60,30 60,13.431458 46.568542,0 30,0 z m 0,10 C 41.045695,10 50,18.954305 50,30 50,41.045695 41.045695,50 30,50 18.954305,50 10,41.045695 10,30 10,18.954305 18.954305,10 30,10 z","connectors":[{"name":"bottom"}]}', "text": "Start" },
   { "Shapes": '{"path":"M74.5,37.5 C74.5,57.91 57.91,74.5 37.5,74.5 C17,74.5 0.5,57.91 0.5,37.5 C0.5,17 17,0.5 37.5,0.5 C57.91,0.5 74.5,17 74.5,37.5 z","connectors":[{"name":"bottom"}]}', "text": "Start" }] ;
```

How to bind the above  json to Listview?

Comment: How this list view should look ? And why the *dataviz*  tag if its about a listview ?

Comment: There is many ways of displaying a listview and your json has many properties. How they should be displayed ? Which properties? It haves a *Shapes* properties, should it be rendered as a chart or something? You question is too vague.

Comment: binding shapes on Kendo  listview

Comment: you have any sample or code ,plz send